# Results of geopandas sjoin_nearest

Tags: python, distance, geopandas

I have 3 datasets for every record of dataset 1, I need to find the nearest point in dataset 2 and 3.

The first step I wanted to do is find the distance for all of dataset 1&2 points, then dataset 1 & 3 points. I was given latitude and longitude for all 3 datasets.

What I have done is convert to crs3857 so I can have them in meters unit and then use distance_col of sjoin_nearest to find the distance in meters.

```
import geopandas as gp

D1df ＝ gp.GeoDataFrame(dataset1,geometry＝gp.points_from_xy(dataset1.Longitude,dataset1.Latitude,crs＝''EPSG:4326'')
D1df = D1df.to_crs(3857)
```

↑same for dataset 2&3

each dataset D1df,D2df &D3df are geopandas dataframe in 3857 coordinate system, geometry column is Point(longitude,latitude)

```
onetwo＝ gp.sjoin_nearest(D1df,D2df,distance_col＝''distancemeters'',how＝''left'')
```

The output looks weird and I'm not sure why, when I use the latitude and longitude and used haversine package &geodesic to check but results are very different

```
import haversine as hs

loc1=(43.139322,-80.242342)

loc2=(43.1391,-80.2440)

hs.haversine(loc1,loc2,unit='m')

from geopy.distance import geodesic

geodesic(loc1,loc2).meters
```

haversine and geodesic gives me 832.627m & 834.217m respectively but geopandas sjoin_nearest output 187.632m Would appreciate if someone can help me understand where I have done wrong and how I can double check.

the sjoin_nearest seems to return more than 1 result of dataset 2 for every row of dataset 1, I expect that with a left join each record in dataset 1 will only match to the closest.

package versions:

```
geopandas 0.12.2

geopy 2.4.0
```

please let me know if you need any other information, thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [How to format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: if you expect that your features are <1 km apart, I would recommend using a projected coordinate system. That simplifies the distance calcs greatly.

Comment: Regarding "the sjoin_nearest seems to return more than 1 result of dataset 2", according to the [ sjoin_nearest docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html) "Results will include multiple output records for a single input record where there are multiple equidistant nearest or intersected neighbors."